# NativeScript Public/Global Functions

Tags: nativescript

Sample Codes:

```
exports.toggleSideDrawer = function() {
  frameModule.topmost().getViewById("sideDrawer").toggleDrawerState();
}
```

How can I use `toggleSideDrawer` without write it in every code-behind file?

For example, I have page A and B, in both of those pages, there's `tap="toggleSideDrawer"`.

In short, make it available to all views/pages in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use global in app.js

*For example*

in app.js

```js
var application = require("application");

global.myGuide = 'John Smith';
global.backToMain = function() {
  global.require('ui/frame').topmost().navigate({
 moduleName: "main-page"
  });
};

application.start({ moduleName: "main-page" });
```

then in any of your code behind files you call the global variables/methods like this

```js
var name = global.myGuide;
global.backToMain();
```

Comment: Thanks @nick-iliev, it's works but in order to call it on code-behind files, I need to wrap it inside the `exports`, if not, it will raise `TypeError Cannot read property bla bla bla`..

Comment: Hi, i know this is old, but i can´t seem to get the result of my global function that i have on my app.js file, what i have is: exports.global.arrNoticias = function () { my http.getJSON request..then i return the result})...then on my other page, hwo do you acces that result through the global function?